# Error generating EJS API documentation

Tags: node.js, ejs, jake

I have downloaded EJS master branch from https://github.com/mde/ejs and proceed to generate full public & private API docs throught the next indication:

> This project uses [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/). For the full public API documentation, clone
>   the repository and run **npm run doc**. This will run JSDoc with the
>   proper options and output the documentation to out/. If you want the
>   both the public & private API docs, run **npm run devdoc** instead.

However i get a error related to [jake](http://jakejs.com/docs), which is already installed.

[image]

**npm-debug.log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'devdoc' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.9
3 info using node@v4.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predevdoc', 'devdoc', 'postdevdoc' ]
5 info predevdoc ejs@2.5.2
6 info devdoc ejs@2.5.2
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info ejs@2.5.2 Failed to exec devdoc script
9 verbose stack Error: ejs@2.5.2 devdoc: `jake doc[dev]`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid ejs@2.5.2
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\    \Desktop\ejs-master
12 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "devdoc"
14 error node v4.6.0
15 error npm  v2.15.9
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error ejs@2.5.2 devdoc: `jake doc[dev]`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the ejs@2.5.2 devdoc script 'jake doc[dev]'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the ejs package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     jake doc[dev]
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs ejs
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls ejs
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```